# composition api doesn't work with Nuxt-TS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Created nuxt app using `npx create-nuxt-app`. Followed documentation at https://typescript.nuxtjs.org, however i have an issue using `@vue/composition-api`:

example component.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ msg }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { createComponent, ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default createComponent({
  setup() {
    const msg = ref('hello')

    return {
      msg
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Doesn't work, throws an error "Property or method "msg" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render." because it doesn't see my `ref`. I've added composition API as plugin in "plugins/composition-api.ts":

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api'

Vue.use(VueCompositionApi)
```

Then in nuxt.config.ts:

`plugins: ['@/plugins/composition-api']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, forgot about TS-runtime in nuxt:

`npm i -S @nuxt/typescript-runtime`

Then you need to update package.json: https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/runtime.html#installation